# Can I activate my "once per turn" effect twice if the activation is negated?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Let's assume I have two copies of ["Spellbook of Secrets"](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Spellbook_of_Secrets) in my hand. I activate one, and my opponent chains to it with their set copy of ["Solemn Judgement"](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Solemn_Judgment). Am I able to activate my second copy? "Spellbook of Secrets"' effect reads:

> Add 1 "Spellbook" card from your Deck to your hand, except "Spellbook of Secrets". You can only activate 1 "Spellbook of Secrets" per turn.

Since "Solemn Judgement" negates the activation of cards, would I be able to activate my other copy, or does it not work that way?

Comment: I wanted to put "hard once per turn" in the title, but I'm unsure if unofficial terminology is alright for this sort of thing. If someone could also clarify rules for that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Good post, the difference between activation and negation is relevant. Regarding the "hard once per turn" to be honest I have never heard it used.

Comment: Hard once per turn, or HOPT, is a pretty common way to label effects like these. It's even used in the page I [linked earlier.](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Once_per_turn) It's in contrast to soft once per turn effects, which cards like Red Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon have that can be activated multiple times per turn, but only once per turn if the card remains face up on the field.

Comment: Not "once per turn if the card remains face up on the field", but once per turn per card is a better way to say it.

Comment: Well, I think that once per turn per card reads more explicitly. However, the term hard per turn could be mentioned in the answer as to inform/encourage about its existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

There is a difference between negating the activation and negating the effects of cards. "Only once per turn" effects, like "Spellbook of Secrets", may only be activated once per turn, and if the activation is negated you can use them again. However, if the effect is negated, say, with something like ["Ash Blossom & Joyous Spring",](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Ash_Blossom_%26_Joyous_Spring) you have still activated the card, and you cannot activate another copy.

You can read more about the distinction among these mechanics [here.](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Once_per_turn)